# JSDB for Android (and other mobile OS)

Tags: javascript, android, sdk

I love the simplicity of JSDB to develop Windows program. Now I want to develop program for Android. I think it will be very useful if there are JSDB equivalent for mobile OS (Android for start).

Any of you know about JSDB equivalent for mobile OS?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is simple in our(programmers) life... btw it become simple after using those tools :). i.e. Eclipse is easy for me but JSDB is really hard for me.

Comment: :-D I guess we have different way to develop program...

Comment: And now, it is 2018, is it anywhere?